# SQL - Finding number of duplicate records for a given day

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to find duplicate records on a given day, that match the provided name. I've achieved a result close to my goal. But this query provides all the rows instead of the rows which are duplicates for a given day.

```
SELECT NameID, DateTime, ROW_Number() over(PARTITION BY NameID, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), DateTime, 111) ORDER BY DateTime ASC) DuplicateCount FROM Employee ORDER BY NameID
```

I only want to return the records for an Employee with more than one NameID entry for a given day. This is running in Visual Studios 2008. I'm returning the results via data reader and populating a list view from there.

Basically, I'm just missing an element that returns only records with a DuplicateCount > 1. If I can limit the results in this way, I'd consider this a win.

Thank you.

**SOLUTION**

Displays NameID, count and the earliest date for an employee with more than one record on a given day.

```
"SELECT sTechID, MIN(Convert(NVARCHAR(25), sDateTime, 10)), COUNT(*) FROM LTI_Scout GROUP BY sTechID, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), sDateTime, 111) HAVING COUNT(*) > 1"
```

Comment: Have you tried using a Group By clause with a HAVING statement?  That is typically how I find duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using the GROUP BY and HAVING clauses in conjunction?  Here is some fake code that might get you started:

```
Select NameID
FROM TableName
GROUP BY NameID, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), DateTime, 111)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: I need the DateTime in the output as well, but when I try to add it to the SELECT NameID, DateTime, it tells me its invalid because its not included in the aggregate function or Group BY Clause. Would you explain how to achieve this?

Comment: Just add it to the Group By clause: GROUP BY NameID, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), DATETIME, 111), DATETIME